# What's the best tool to use to convert scanned PDFs so they can be indexed in SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, search, pdf, ifilter, crawling

I have a large amount of PDFs and I need to be able to search them in MOSS 2007. I am aware of the iFilter which is required, but it will not index scanned PDFs. What is the fastest way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image PDFs do behave differently than those created from word docs.  You can probably get some OCR tools to help.  Its been awhile, but I think KnowledgeLake had the ability to OCR and auto-index some of the scanned documents.

Comment: I use KnowledgeLake and I can vouch for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I heard that [ABBYY FineReader 10](http://www.pdftransformer.com/) is a very good software to do this (I never tried it). It will probably include some DEV work on your side to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Acrobat Pro. It contains an OCR Text Recognition batch command that will convert entire folders.

Comment: IS there a way to automate this to do so in batches? or they need to be done manually one by one?