# Scanning documents to a SharePoint folder

Tags: 2010

I want when scanning documents to select a folder in SharePoint where to save the document. It should be something cost effective and easy to use.

Can you recommend a software product or some advices hot we could develop such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There are several posts here on Sharepoint Stack Exchange.  A simple search would get you pretty far.

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=ocr
- [Most Efficient Way to Scan Large Volume of Records/Documents into SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53779/most-efficient-way-to-scan-large-volume-of-records-documents-into-sharepoint)
- [Thoughts on OCR Solutions for SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11361/thoughts-on-ocr-solutions-for-sharepoint/11362#11362)
- [What's the best tool to use to convert scanned PDFs so they can be indexed in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/831/whats-the-best-tool-to-use-to-convert-scanned-pdfs-so-they-can-be-indexed-in-sh/836#836)
  -

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Udocx. It establishes a secure connection between your scanner and SharePoint and saves scans as searchable documents. 
Visit the [Udocx website](http://www.udocx.com/SharePoint) for more information